# Facebook iCalendar files in wrong language

Tags: facebook, http, http-headers

My app supports synchronizing events by downloading iCalendar files.  When attempting to download iCalendar files from Facebook, the Facebook server returns files in the wrong language in some cases.

As a US user, the file always seems to download in the language I selected on the Facebook website (my "primary Facebook language").  This is the correct functionality.

For international users, this doesn't always seem to be the case.  Many users have selected "English" as their primary language, but they are getting a localized language version of the file anyways, based on their location:  e.g.  A user in India receives a Hindi version of the file, a user in Israel receives a Hebrew version.

Is there a way to override Facebook's behavior to send the correct version of the file?  What parameters to an HTTP request could I modify to attempt to force Facebook to send a particular language?  Is there a URL parameter or subdomain that might get them to send the file in the correct language?

The current code to download the iCalendar file:

```
        urlString = "https://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?<user-auth-params>"
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
        String ical = "";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (in.read(buffer, 0, 1024) > 0) {
            ical += new String(buffer).replaceAll("[^\\P{C}\\s]", "");
        }
        //Log.v(TAG, "stream: " + ical);
        httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
```

Comment: I think you should provide more detailed info in order to allow the rest of us to replicate this behaviour. How are you downloading this files? which HTTP request are you using? It might be some small mistake of you and people will help to highlight it if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I added to my original question the code that I am currently using to download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, for people who are interested in this answer, Facebook accepts the query parameter "&locale=xx-XX" as part of the query string to specify the language and localization settings for the file.

Specifying a specific locale seems to have solved this issue.